# What is the difference between preprocessor directive vs directive in C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I would like to know what is the exact difference between those two terms.
some search results say that # is the signal for preprocessor and next to that 
symbol would be the directive. As example

"#" :- preprocessor symbol

"include" :- directive

So `#include` call as preprocessor directive itself. If so, please tell me examples for the preprocessor directive vs directive in C++ ?

Comment: There are no non-preprocessor directives. It is not clear why you assume they exist.

Comment: @n.m ok I will update that non preprocessor word towards to my original question then thanks.

Comment: @77bizmarck When you ask "preprocessor directive" vs "directive" you essentially ask if there is some directive that is not a preprocessor directive. It doesn't matter if you call it "non-preprocesor directive" or not. There is no such thing. `#` symbol followed by a command like `include` is one entity. They don't exist separately.

Comment: Instead of "some search results", learn the language from [a proper book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) whose author knows what they're talking about.

Answer (score 3):

`#include` is the start of a preprocessor directive. It consists of a `#` character followed by the directive's name. There are then additional pieces of information that come after it. An example of a full preprocessor directive might be:

```
#include <string>
```

It *directs* the preprocessor to do something (in this case, to include the `string` header).

The term "directive" may also be found in other contexts in C++. For example, the following is a [*using-directive*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace):

```
using namespace std;
```

I would advise not getting hung up on the word "directive". It's just an English term for "a command to do a thing".